# How to ORDER BY a certain value inside a row in a SELECT function?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's what the string within the row looks like:

```
{
    "boost": {
        "status": "true",
        "position": 27,
        "start_rounds": "100",
        "rounds": 18
    },
    "vip": {
        "status": "true",
        "expired": 1566763202
    },
    "top":
        {"status":"true",
        "position":"16",
        "expired":"1570953660"
    }
}
```

Now, I need to order the list by the part of this row, specifically by expired date in "vip" section.

like

```
SELECT * FROM `servers` ORDER BY **expired part of string in `services` column**
```

Is this possible within MySQL at all? I tried SUBSTRING but it doesn't work since it's a very complicated string structure.

I usually use json_decode when working with it in php. But I want to know if it's possible to sort them within MySQL.

I use MySQL version 5.7.27

Comment: Which DB and which version do you use?

Comment: MySQL Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Postgres :

```
select * from servers ORDER BY [ColumnName]->>'expired' ASC
```

For Mysql :

```
SELECT id, name, JSON_EXTRACT([ColumnName], '$.expired')  AS expired
FROM servers 
ORDER BY expired ASC
```

Mysql Multi-level, you can specify the level name. For example, if you want to order by the 'expired' under 'vip :

```
SELECT id, name,JSON_EXTRACT([ColumnName], '$.vip.expired') AS expired
FROM servers 
ORDER BY expired ASC
```

Reference : [Query a multi-level JSON object stored in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756438/query-a-multi-level-json-object-stored-in-mysql)

Comment: Unfortunately there are other "expired" values in services at the same time sometimes so I'm not sure if this will work. It needs to be specified for "vip".

Answer (score 0):

in Postgre you can use json operators for this

```
select
    x,
    x -> 'vip' ->> 'expired' as expired_string
from
    (select '{"boost":{"status":"true","position":27,"start_rounds":"100","rounds":18},"vip":{"status":"true","expired":1566763202}}'::json as x)
order by
    x -> 'vip' ->> 'expired'
```